# How to check transferred file is not changed

Tags: c#, checksum

I have a `web service` and I am going to access the `database` over that web service. I am going to save a text file to my DB using web service.

Before saving file to the DB I want to make sure that that the file not changed.

I have no idea to how to do this. Can please anybody explain me how to do this. Specifying the steps would be enough.

**EDIT**

I am passing my text file to the web service as `byte array`. In other words I want to make sure all the bytes which I sent, has received to the web service as it is.(not corrupted nor loose of data). I have control over the web service as well.

Comment: What creates the text file? How would you expect to determine if the file has changed?

Comment: You want to open a file with a exclusive lock or ...?

Comment: read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum
  this should help http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate checksum of file, to validate it on client.

```
string checkSum=null;
using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create()) {
  checkSum= BitConverter.ToString(
    md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theString))
  ).Replace("-", String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Where should I place this. Client or server side or on both sides?

Comment: On server you should calculate and send info to client.And  on client you should calculate and check is same value

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't need to check that, you have different communication layers that do that for you.

If a package is lost during transport, it will be resent, and if damaged, will be corrected/sent again. assuming you are using **TCP/IP protocol** , your transport layer guarantees that data will transfer properly, without you having to deal with it.

*(this is a file and not a streaming video, **UDP protocol** will have possible corruption of data, which is ok in video/audio)*

*Just to clear things up: you are at the application layer.
[image: Example of layers]

**Edit:**

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) regarding TCP/IP:

*This abstraction also allows upper layers to provide services that the lower layers do not provide. While the original OSI model was extended to include connectionless services (OSIRM CL),[16] IP is not designed to be reliable and is a best effort delivery protocol. This means that all transport layer implementations must choose whether or how to provide reliability. UDP provides data integrity via a checksum but does not guarantee delivery; **TCP provides both data integrity and delivery guarantee by retransmitting until the receiver acknowledges the reception of the packet**.*